# Return only returning last item

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Dish = namedtuple('Dish', 'name price calories')
da = Dish("Mac N' Cheese", 8.00, 750)
db = Dish('Grilled Cheese', 6.50, 500)
dc = Dish('Hamburger', 9.50, 1000)
dd = Dish('Caeser Salad', 8.25, 650)
de = Dish('Fish Tacos', 11.25, 1150)

DL = [ da, db, dc, dd, de ]
```

I need to change the price of all the items in DL by a certain percentage but the function i wrote only returns de

```
def Dishlist_change_price(DL: list, percentage: float) -> list:
    result = [ ]
    x = percentage/100
    for i in DL:
        y = i.price + (i.price * x)
        result = i._replace(price = y)
    return result
```

What is wrong in the code for it to only return the last Dish?

Comment: Minor side-note: Defining `x = 1 + percentage / 100` then `y = i.price * x` would simplify the code and reduce floating point error. Of course, floating point is an awful data type for financial data; switching to `decimal.Decimal` or at least changing to `y = round(i.price * x, 2)` would get you whole cents instead of partial pennies with growing error as you repeatedly adjust prices.

Answer (score 2):

You have `result = i._replace(price = y)` so on each iteration through the loop you change result to be the most recent DL. What you need is `result.append(i._replace(price = y))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use append() method to add an element into list:

```
def Dishlist_change_price(DL: list, percentage: float) -> list:
    result = []
    x = percentage / 100
    for i in DL:
        y = i.price + (i.price * x)
        result.append(i._replace(price=y))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the last line to append to the array

like result.append(i._replace(price = y)

Answer (score 0):

```
result = i._replace(price = y)
```

rebinds `result` to the new `namedtuple` object returned by `_replace()`. As this happens once for each item in the list, only the last one is returned from your function. You should use `list.append()` instead:

```
result.append(i._replace(price = y))
```

or better yet, a list comprehension:

```
def Dishlist_change_price(DL: list, percentage: float) -> list:
    x = 1 + percentage/100.0
    return [d._replace(price=(d.price*x)) for d in DL]
```

You probably shouldn't be using `_replace()`; the leading underscore in the method name suggests that it is intended for private use within the class. (See [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) regarding identifiers with leading underscores). However, as `_replace()` is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace), and is available in both versions of Python, it's unlikely that it will disappear or be changed. Nevertheless, a safer way is to explicitly instantiate a new `Dish` within a list comprehension like this:

```
def Dishlist_change_price(DL: list, percentage: float) -> list:
    x = 1 + percentage/100.0
    return [Dish(d.name, d.price*x, d.calories) for d in DL]
```